# SQL multiple select query and intersect on the same table

Tags: sql-server

I am querying to get three columns (A,B,S) based on the top 200 of the Sum of third column (S) of a table (this has some condition checks).

```
SELECT TOP 200 PlantId, SKU, SUM(Demand)
FROM NetDemandTable
WHERE DemandWKId>=62 AND DemandWKId<=76
GROUP BY PlantId, SKU
ORDER BY SUM(Demand) DESC
```

The resultant Column B is considered as a unique records for the other select query which is again A,B,S columns, but with different condition and the this column B should intersect with the Results obtained in select Query 1.

```
SELECT PlantId, SKU, SUM(Demand)
FROM CuringNetDemandCopy
WHERE DemandWKId < 62 
GROUP BY PlantId, SKU  
ORDER BY SUM(Demand) DESC
```

Now the second query results should select only the entities of SKU in Column B obtained from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with  cte as 
(
SELECT TOP 200 PlantId, SKU, SUM(Demand)
FROM NetDemandTable
WHERE DemandWKId>=62 AND DemandWKId<=76
GROUP BY PlantId, SKU
)

SELECT PlantId, SKU, SUM(Demand)
FROM CuringNetDemandCopy
WHERE DemandWKId < 62  and SKU in (select distinct SKU from cte)
GROUP BY PlantId, SKU  
ORDER BY SUM(Demand) DESC
```

Comment: I think, "EXISTS" clause should be use here.BTW  
@Rajasekhar Kadambur,what output r u looking for.Like what is the main purpose of query 1